# Doctrine nested condition (andWhere) with join

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I want to do something like this with my `QueryBuilder`:

```
$query = $qb
        ->select('u')
        ->from('AppBundle:School', 'u')
        ->where('u.superAdmin = :user')
        ->andWhere(
            $qb->join('u.admins', 'admins')
                ->where('admins = :user'))
        ->setParameters(array(':user' => $userArray))
        ->getQuery();
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your SchoolRepository.php :

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->where('u.superAdmin = :user')
    ->leftJoin('u.admins', 'a')
    ->andWhere('a = :user')
    ->setParameter('user', $userArray)
    ->getQuery()
;

$results = $query->getResult();
```